# Fluid Arrangement of Cells

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

http://www.bootply.com/ySKc5Jc7B4

---

The initial arrangement is:

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
```

If I now gradually decrease the window's size then the grid suddenly jumps to:

```
1
2
...
6
```

I would like to have an intermediate step with two columns:

```
1 2
3 4
5 6
```

I assume this behaviour is called fluid(ity) - hence I tried the `container-fluid` class for the container `div`. But that didn't do it and furthermore messed with the initial grid sizing.

Is it possible to make a grid behave in such a sensible way?

(I'm pretty new to Twitter Bootstrap (3))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure.  You just need to change the class names on your tiles.

Go from `col-md-4` to a combination like `col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-xs-12`.  What that's telling it to do is:

1. For large screens, take up 4 of 12 columns.
2. For medium screens, take up 6 of 12 columns.
3. For very small screens, take up 12 of 12 columns.

Hope that helps.

## [Example here](http://www.bootply.com/CtW84QkUgm)